# Google map is not opening in Edge using Angular.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, microsoft-edge

I am trying to display location on Google Map using Angular.js/JavaScript. The problem is it's not working in Microsoft Edge like browser. My code is below.

```
$scope.latitude=$stateParams.latitude;
$scope.longitude=$stateParams.longitude;
$scope.title=$stateParams.title;
//$scope.restName=$stateParams.restName;
var desc= $scope.latitude+","+ $scope.longitude;
console.log($scope.latitude,$scope.longitude);
var markers = [{"lat":$scope.latitude,"lng":$scope.longitude},{"title": $scope.title,"lat":$scope.latitude,"lng":$scope.longitude,"description":desc}];
$window.onload = function () {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatlng,
       map: map,
       title: data.title
     });
     latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
     (function (marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
          infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
          infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      })(marker, data);
   }
   map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
   map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
   zoomChangeBoundsListener = 
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event){
     if (this.getZoom()){
        this.setZoom(12);
     }
    });
   setTimeout(function({
     google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener)}, 2000);
   }
```

This is working in all browser except Microsoft Edge. For IE11 it was not working but after clearing cache it is opening but all time clearing cache is not a solution.

Comment: I think IE does not like onload event. Perhaps try another way

Comment: @grogro : any alternative solution for this ?

Comment: You can try to init what you need in app.run() then use it in your controller. This directive seems to be a good solution too https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

Comment: You can also try to replace $window.onload = function () {...} by $timeout(function(){...})

Comment: yes,i removed onload function and put $timeOut it started works.